# node doesn't reflect changes on project when deploying

Tags: node.js, sass

I have updated node for my project to reflect the issue I've had when trying to deploy:

```
error sass@1.55.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.0.0". Got "10.24.0"
```

But now when the Node is updated, I am still getting the same message.

My updated node version in the project is v16.17.1 when checking the version.

How come the project still "gives" the old node and not the new one when deploying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a DOCKER issue.

I've updated node for my project but not for my docker containers, I had to rebuild my containers with the updated node to fix this.